# Using ICSP pins as SPI in Arduino Due

Tags: spi, arduino-due, rfid, icsp

I am using two RFID sensors operating on SPI with arduino Due. They will not be operating at the same time.
Is it favorable to use the ICSP pins as SPI pins for one of them, or use them in a one master two slaves configuration with the SPI header?

Comment: on Due there is no ICSP programming. those pins are only for SPI

Comment: The Due's SPI is odd, to say the least. From what I recall, it doesn't *have* multiple SPI ports. Instead it uses multiple hardware SS pins to look like multiple ports in hardware. Just stick to one channel with multiple slaves. The Due is just a mess. It's no wonder it got retired in short order...

Comment: @Majenko, Due is not retired

Comment: @Juraj They resurrected it?! Morons! The Due is the second worst Arduino of all time, only beaten by the Intel Galileo abortion.